# Lookup Comma Seperating Values in R

Tags: r

I am new to this community, currently working on a R project in which I need to find each of the element separated by comma in a dataframe, on any of the columns in another dataframe, here is an example below:

```
#DataFrame1
    a=c("AA,BB","BB,CC,FF","CC,DD,GG,FF","GG","")
        df1=as.data.frame(a)

#DataFrame2
x=c("AA","XX","BB","YY","ZZ","MM","YY","CC")
y=c("DD""VV","NN","XX","CC","AA","WW","FF")
z=c("CC","AA","YY","GG","HH","OO","PP","QQ")
df2=as.data.frame(x,y,z)
```

what I need to do is find, if any of the elements, lets take for example "AA,BB" (which is the first cell in column x of `df1`) "AA" is an element and "BB" is another element , is available on any of the columns (x,y,x) in `df2`, if a match is found I need to identify that row or rows, there is also a possibility of more then one match on `df2` rows
. Hope I was able to explain this problem well, expert please help

Comment: missing a "," in vector y (should be y=c("DD", "VV",...

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the example you gave?

Comment: I would like output something like this...
x=c("AA","XX","BB","YY","ZZ","MM","YY","CC")
y=c("DD""VV","NN","XX","CC","AA","WW","FF")
z=c("CC","AA","YY","GG","HH","OO","PP","QQ")
output=x("AA,BB","AA","BB","GG","CC","AA","","CC,FF")
df.output<-data.frame(x,y,x,ouput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a solution in 2 steps:

`# load tidyverse
library(tidyverse)`

Step 1: Split the elements separated by comma from `df1` in a new data frame `new_df`

1a) To do this, we first identify the number of columns to be generated
(as the maximum number of elements separated by `,`; that is: maximum number of `,` + 1)

`number_new_columns <- max(sapply(df1$a, function(x) str_count(x, ","))) + 1`

1b) Generate the new data frame `new_df`

```
    new_df <- df1 %>% 
    separate(a, c(as.character(seq_len(number_new_columns)))) # missing pieces will be filled with NA

    # Above, we used c(as.character(seq_len(number_new_columns))) to generate column names as numbers -- not very creative :)
```

Step 2: Identify the position of each unique element from `new_df` in `df2`
(hope I understood correctly this second part of the question)

2a) Get the unique elements (from `new_df`)

`unique_elements <- unlist(new_df) %>%
  unique()`

2b) Get a list whose components contain the positions of each unique element within `df2`

```
output <- lapply(unique_elements, function(x) {
   which(df2 == x, arr.ind=TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Luminita, Excellent.... this is giving me a map, is there a way if I can bind the <output> to <df2>

Comment: @karthic I'm not sure I understand your aim. Do you want to extract back the rows that were mapped to have at least one element present, and then bind_rows back to df2? You can extract back the rows by: 
`rows_extract <- lapply(1:length(output), function(i) {

  mapped_rows <- output[[i]][,"row"];
  df2[mapped_rows,]
})`

Then, get unique observations in a df:
`bind_rows((rows_extract)) %>% unique()`

Comment: Thank You Luminita, it was very helpful!